# how can i use jdbcTemplate for Date field dynamically?

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

how can i map following query in jdbctemplate

```
    select count(*),trim(rdate)
    from man 
    where r='AGREE' and
    rdate LIKE date '2016-04-12'
    group by trim(rdate);
```

where i am sending date argument  dynamically and this query/method  should return type int only.
query in jdbc template should be like

```
select count(*),trim(rdate)
    from man 
    where r='AGREE' and
    rdate LIKE date ?
    group by trim(rdate);
```

where i replace date with ? and it should return type  int only
can anyone help me for this?

Comment: remove the "group by" and "trim(rdate)"?

Comment: yes if result is same then np